# How can I display a message to the user for this code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a Boat Mooring reservations program, and currently, the way it works is, after you enter your name and click a button, the program gives you the next available mooring, there are 6 piers and 5 moorings per pier.

So, after all the moorings and piers are used up, the program crashes becuase there is nowhere for it to go, how can I make it so that the user gets a message box telling them, that there are no more spots available?

This is my code:

Button click:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var req = new BoatRequest();
    req.Name = txtName.Text;
    var client = new BoatReserveSoapClient();
    BoatResponse response = client.ReserveMooring(req);

    if (req != null)
    {
        Pierlbl.Text = response.Pier.ToString();
        Mooringlbl.Text = response.Mooring.ToString();
        Pierlbl.Visible = true;
        Mooringlbl.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Pierlbl.Text = "Error Occured, please try again";
        Mooringlbl.Text = "Error Occured, please try again";
    }
}
```

The web method:

```
//Setting the max value for Piers and Moorings
public const int maxPiers = 6;
public const int maxMoorings = 30;
private static bool[,] reserveMooring = new bool[maxPiers, maxMoorings];

[WebMethod]
public BoatResponse ReserveMooring(BoatRequest req)
{
    var res = new BoatResponse();

    //if pierCalc set to 0, if smaller than maxPiers increment
    for (int pierCalc = 0; pierCalc < maxPiers; pierCalc++)
    {
        //if mooringCalc set to 0, if smaller than maxMoorings increment
        for (int mooringCalc = 0; mooringCalc < maxMoorings / maxPiers; mooringCalc++)
        {
            if (!reserveMooring[pierCalc, mooringCalc])
            {
                reserveMooring[pierCalc, mooringCalc] = true;
                res.Pier = (Pier)pierCalc;
                res.Mooring = (Mooring)mooringCalc;
                return res;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is where it crashes:

```
Pierlbl.Text = response.Pier.ToString();
```

Comment: However you construct this, please don't tell them to try again - tell them that there are no moorings available, and if possible, tell them when one might be available in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the `response` is not null, like this:

```
if (response != null)
{
    Pierlbl.Text = response.Pier.ToString();
    Mooringlbl.Text = response.Mooring.ToString();
    Pierlbl.Visible = true;
    Mooringlbl.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    Pierlbl.Text = "Error Occured, please try again";
    Mooringlbl.Text = "Error Occured, please try again";
}
```

Comment: +1 check the response from the request, not the request itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should just check if response != null and if it's the case, show the user a message.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, **req** is never going to equal **null**. the **response** object is receiving the return value from your Web Service and would therefore the one to check for a null value in your if statement.

Like so:

```
 if (response != null)
        {
            //Logic for success
        }
        else
        {
            //Logic for failure
        }
```